# Unable to instantiate COM+ objects installed via exported application

Tags: com, com-interop, com+, createobject, typelib

I have a COM+ application that has been exported to an MSI using Component Services and then installed on a test server. The web application (ASP) is unable to instantiate any of the objects it uses from the COM+ application.

The COM+ application consists of three DLLs built in VB6. There is one DLL each for data, application and presentation layers. The web application only uses objects from the presentation layer. The COM+ DLLs call into a couple of .NET DLLs exposed via COM.

When the web application runs, an `HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error` is returned. No errors appear in the application or system log.

I've tried instantiating the objects from VBScript using `WSH.CreateObject` and it works only for objects in the data layer. When trying to create object in the application or presentation layer I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not create object named "My.ProgId" 
Code: 800A801D
Source: WScript.CreateObject
```

Because it fails from VBScript, I suspect that the ASP app is fine and that it is the COM+ application that has issues.

## Extra Info

If I uninstall the COM+ application and try to run my VBScript to test instantiation, I get a different error.

```
Error: Could not locate automation class named "My.ProgId" 
Code: 80020009
Source: WScript.CreateObject
```

Since the errors are different, it seems that COM is at least finding the COM+ objects when they're installed, it's just not able to instantiate them.

I've also tried monitoring the script with ProcessMon. I can see WScript.exe (via COM) querying the registry for the ProgID, and then the CLSID. Eventually the path to the DLL is pulled back and then svchost.exe and dllhost.exe query the registry for the same information using the CLSID and also getting back the path to the DLL. Eventually the DLL has a *Load Image* operation against it followed by the same for msvbvm60.dll. I don't see anything that points to a failure accessing the COM+ DLL.

I've now tried installing the COM+ application to another Win2k3 server and a Windows XP desktop. I'm getting the same result with being able to instantiate objects from the data layer DLL, but not from the application and presentation layer DLLs. I've also tried getting an old copy of the application layer DLL and *I am* able to successfully instantiate objects from it. However, when I compare the project files for the two different versions, nothing stands out as being a possible cause of this problem.

Comment: Does your Presentation layer dll have a `Main` routine?  Does the object you are trying to initialise have a `Class_Initialise`?  If so what exception handling have you placed in these places?  Do the presentation layer and business layer have other dependencies that my not be inplace on the target server?

Comment: No `Main` routine and no `Class_Initialise`. Some of the classes have an `ObjectControl_Activate`, but that shouldn't fire until a method is called I believe. The error handling that is present in some of the methods, including inside `ObjectControl_Activate`, is a traditional VB6 `On Error GoTo X` error handler which logs the error to the event log using `App.LogEvent` and then raises a new error. I believe all the dependencies are installed, but I'll double check.

Comment: On my dev machine, when there have been problems the error handling code is successfully writing to the event log. On the test server, the event logs are *not* being written to by the DLLs.

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but has the progid been registered on the system?

Comment: Yup it has. When I used **ProcessMon** I could see COM querying the registry and then loading the DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application layer DLL was referencing a `struct` defined in a .NET assembly. The error was caused by the type library containing the `struct` not being registered on the deployment machine.

When building the .NET assembly in Visual Studio, it would create a type library for the assembly and register it. When the app was deployed, the .NET assemblies were registered using `regasm /codebase <assemblyname.dll>`. That would register the classes so that they could be instantiated, but it did not register any structs.

The solution was to use `regtlib.exe` to register the type library on the test server.

The error messages were of no help at all when trying to discover the cause of the problem. Come on Microsoft!!

Comment: You forgot regasm's /tlb option